# Allowed to use multiple YouTube API keys for 1 project?

Tags: api, google-api, youtube-data-api

I am quickly reaching quota limits while using YouTube Data API v3 for searches only using 1 API key.

I have applied for Quota increase but I hear it can take some time.

However I landed on the below article which states that a max of 300 APIs can be used for 1 project. Are my really allowed to use multiple YouTube Data API v3 keys and switch between them each time quota limit is reached??

https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/api-keys

I had been scrambling for solutions. I hope I read it well!

Answer (score 1):

Keys and credentials within a project share their quota.  Creating additional  api keys within the same project on google developer console is not going to get you additional quota.

As seen below all the credentials her will share the same quota.

[image]

You would need to create additional projects and create a key within each project.

All of these projects have their own credentials with their own quotas.

[image]

You should wait for an extension These days it shouldn't take more then a couple of weeks to hear back about a quota increase.

Comment: Ow interesting! So creating multiple projects API keys won't jeopardize my request for quota increase? As in is it considered as cheating and could make me get penalized for abusing the system (though not sure if it's considered as that)?

Comment: Lets try this again.   Creating multiple **PROJECTS** with one key in each will give you the 10k quota for each of the projects.    Creating more then one key within the same project they will all use the same quota.    Creating more projects wont effect your request for quota increase as you requested quota from a single project.

Comment: Yes I see your point. However I am speaking more in terms of legality. As in would I be violating the terms of use or other, if I am doing such workaround of using multiple keys for one website just to overcome the quota limitations? Wondering in case YouTube could ban my domain for such workaround, if ever they test my website.

Comment: Stack Overflow cant answer legal questions, contact a lawyer.  However I question why you would want to do such a thing in a production environment.   Just apply for a quota extension.  Its reasonably painless.  That's what its there for.  The default quota is only intended for development not for production google expects you to request an extension.

Comment: As explained initially, Quota extension already applied for since a few days. Default quota is slowing down development, testing and reviews as it only allows for less than 100 search requests. Too bad there is no testing mode for the API with mock data. And too poor to go through the process of hiring a lawyer to answer this one question :)

Comment: good luck let me know when you get an extension.  I am keeping count of the average response time.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is yes and no (but probably more **no** than yes in your case).

YES, you are allowed to use multiple Youtube Data API v3 keys and switch between but NO, you can't switch between them because you reached the quota limitation.

By doing so, you violate Youtube's Developer Policies compliance and expose yourself to sanctions. The only reason you should switch between them is to separate your environments.

From the Youtube's Developer Policies :

> Don’t create multiple Google Cloud projects for the same API service or use case in an attempt to deceptively acquire an API quota that is higher than the one your project was assigned.
> It is acceptable to have a separate API Project for each different use case of your API service. Examples include:
> One API project for your iOS app, a separate API Project for your Android app.
> One API project for a production server, one for a development server.
> One API project for your user-facing API service, one API project for internal system analytics

source : https://developers.google.com/youtube/terms/developer-policies-guide#don%E2%80%99t_spread_api_access_across_multiple_or_unknown_projects